# How to assign peripherals to physical pins for STM32 MCUs?

Tags: stm32, peripheral-pin-select

I'm using STM32F series MCUs with a RTOS. Since the OS provides API to configure the peripherals and their physical output assignment, I didn't pay much attention in the past. Now I want to have full control of this type of hardware configurations.

The point I've confused is that, according to datasheet, a physical pin might be in one of 3 different modes (for STM32F103, in this case):

1. `Main function (after reset)`
2. `Primary alternate function (Alternate function/Default)`
3. `Remapped alternate function`

"Main function" is easy to understand. However, for example, one primary alternate function *can be assigned* to 3 different peripherals for the same physical pin:

[image]

## Question

Where are we configuring if `PA2` is used for whether `USART2_TX` or `ADC12_IN2` or `TIM2_CH3`?

Comment: This is different on the various STM32's, the F100 series being old and odd, for that look at the alternate function remap.  There are no guard rails, you have to do this yourself.

Comment: Check out STM32CubeMX for configuration.

Comment: what that is saying is the pin can be connected to those three things internally it defaults to one and can be switched to one of the others using the alternate function settings.  That or one of the other documents for that chip will show the table of alternate functions for each pin (using the PA2 names not the F3, or k3 type pin names) and then the alternate function register will show the bit pattern and bits you need to use switch PA2 to that particular internal perihperal and thus function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are we configuring if PA2 is used whether USART2_TX or ADC12_IN2 or TIM2_CH3?

Every GPIO has a Port configuration register (GPIOx_CRL/GPIOx_CRH).
The STM32F1 series also has AFIO (alternate function input output) registers with remap bits. These are per function, not per pin. See AFIO_MAPR.

The REMAP register is where things get difficult, because this remaps multiple pins.

To solve this puzzle I recommend you use the STM32Cube initialization code generator.

> Is it the operating systems' or the STM's headers' responsibility generating an error message if we try to configure PA2 as both USART2_TX and ADC12_IN2?

It it physically not possible to configure PA2 as USART2_TX **and** ADC_IN12.

To put it in `ADC_IN12`, you only set CNF to Analog and MODE to input.
To put it in `USART2_TX` set CNF `push-pull` *and* enable alternate function.
To put it in `TIM2_CH3`, set CNF to `floating` or `push-pull`, enable alternate function, and enable `TIM2_REMAP` in AFIO_MAPR.

Analog mode has priority. This disables the digital features, such as schmitt trigger and output control.

*(You might still be able to use the ADC while digital input/output functions are enabled, I have never tried this)*

[image]

> both settings for TIM2_CH3 and USART2_TX have the same configuration

That is because they require the same functionality.
REMAP configures if you use TIM or USART.

Comment: Is this the procedure used when you're using ChibiOS?

Comment: @ScottSeidman No, ChibiOS provides an API and takes care of those under the hood.

Comment: @ceremcem -- if you can summarize that, you might provide an answer, because it looks like the question is for a ChipiOS solution.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I've cleaned up the question and provide an answer.

Comment: @Jeroen3: Could you please verify the procedural way [that I understood](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/422280/20285) and remove the section of your answer to the unnecessary part of my question about "who is responsible for generating error"?

Answer (score 0):

## Reinterpreting the Answer

Procedural way to assign peripherals to physical pins is as follows:

1. You may use any pin whose `Pinout.Type is I/O` as GPIO. [Configure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5v8P.png) in/out selection by "GPIO Configuration Register (GPIO_CR = GPIOx_CR{H+L})".
2. You may use any GPIO pin as ADC input if "ADCx_INy" is listed in its "Alternate Functions" column. Configure "Analog mode" by GPIO_CR.
3. You may connect an on-chip peripheral to its dedicated pins. To do so:

   1. Decide which peripheral to use (USARTx, SPIx, PWMx/y (=TIMx_CHy)).
   2. Decide whether if you want to use the peripheral with its default pinouts or alternative pinouts. (A peripheral might have optional physical connections. See REMAP column of Pinouts Table)
   3. Wire the peripheral's input(s) and/or output(s) to the physical pins you have chosen in the previous step. (see "GPIO configurations of the device peripherals" section in the RM.)

      1. Inputs: Enable the "Alternate Function Output" (despite the confusing word "output") in GPIO_CR.
      2. Outputs: Enable the "Alternate Function Output" in GPIO_CR.
      3. If more than one on-chip peripheral outputs are listed in the same physical pin column, then **you have to** refer to further registers  to select which peripheral to enable (or see the default peripheral). Specific alternate function (peripheral) is selected via:

         1. AFIO_MAPR register for STM32F1xx
         2. AFR_x register for STM32F03x

#### Notes for connecting a peripheral:

The developer (or the RTOS library is) responsible for generating the compiler errors if two or more conflicting peripheral (which needs use the same physical pin) is mistakenly enabled at the same time. However, as we are able to change the peripheral setup in the runtime, it's unlikely to expect such a compile-time error.